# How to insert a string between two other strings while printing in Python

Tags: python, string

I have two strings word1 and word2. I want to add " 's " to the first string while printing.

```
word1 = "king"
word2 = "cross"
print(word1+word2)
```

Comment: expected output?

Comment: *"I have an issue with the following code."* What is the exact issue you face with that code?

Comment: You know how to use string literals since you used them to assign values to those variables. You know how to concatenate strings since you did that in the `print` line. Surely, it's just a small step to get from there to `print(word1 + "'s " + word2)`, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `+ "'s"`

```
print(word1 + "'s " + word2)
```